# VBScript and running a macro from an excel spreadshet

Tags: excel, vbscript, macros

I have tried and tried and tried, and nearing my limits now. Originally i was trying to run a macro from PERSONAL.XLSB, and kept running into ' The Macro may not be available in this workbook, or macros not enabled Code: 800A03EC.' So i moved onto just a plain test workbook.xlsm, added Module1 in developer. (Presuming there were issues with PERSONAL.) I am still getting the same errors.

The workbook opens fine, it always errors on .Run.

In the code below i have included the various variations i have tried off .Run, no doubt i have done something very silly and the problem in obvious.

The workbook opens fine.

```
'On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFolder = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName,"\"))
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
Set file = folder.Files


'edit excel csv file.
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
filePath = SFolder & "MMFILE_2ndWave_20161205_CUSTOMER.xlsm"
Set xlBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, True)

objExcel.Visible = True



objExcel.Run filePath & "!Module1"
'objExcel.Run "Module1"
'objExcel.Run "'MMFILE_2ndWave_20161205_CUSTOMER.xlsm'!Module1"
'objExcel.Application.Run "Module1"
'objExcel.Application.Run filePath & "!Module1"
'objExcel.Application.Run "'" & xlBook1.Name & "'!Module.Module3"   

msgbox "finished"
```

Comment: I couldnt edit my post, but the macro runs fine from within the spreadsheet.

Comment: "just a plain test workbook.xlsm, added Module1 in developer." Yes, but how is the `Sub` named where the macro code is in? And where do you think you are calling that `Sub`?

Comment: Sub Module1(), not sure what you mean by 'where do you think you are calling that sub?'

Comment: So your `Sub` is named `Module1` but then how is your Module named? If it is also named `Module1`, then `objExcel.Run "'" & filePath & "'!Module1.Module1"`.

Comment: Axel, you are a genius! Worked a treat. I had no idea i needed to name the module and the sub. Briliant, ty, you have saved what hair i have left!!!

Comment: Calling module and sub would not be necessary if you had not named the sub exactly as the module. Why do you do so? If the `Sub` would be named `test`, then `objExcel.Run "'" & filePath & "'!test"` would work.

Comment: To be honest i will be running multiple macros with various subs and functions, so either way it is good to know this! But taken on board, where it is not needed, i will call the sub directly.